# sbt silently fails to import a dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt is driving me nuts, by suddenly not pulling in a dependency any more. The setup is as follows

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org" %% "foo" % "1.2",
  "org" %% "bar" % "3.4"
)
```

After an `sbt clean update`, I am missing the `bar` library. E.g.

```
$ ls lib_managed/jars/org/
foo_2.10
```

Consequently the compilation fails because that library is missing.

This is with sbt 0.12.3. What is the **magic spell** to make it behave again and reconsider importing my library? Something I should wipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wipe:

```
$ rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache/org/
```

Comment: As a side note that error reappears each time I seem to be doing an sbt update in the local `bar` project, which is kind of... unusual, to say the least.