# sbt ignoring library dependency

Tags: scala, classpath, sbt, dependency-management

I have a library dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "mygroup" % "myartifact" % "myversion"
```

This is properly retrieved, and found in `lib_managed`. It contains some XML files (resources), and using `jar tf` I can see that the jar file is complete.

Ok. But—although this had always been working before—it is **not ending up on my classpath any more**. When I do `show full-classpath`, I see all libraries but this one. Consequently the program fails because it cannot read these resources. This also effects bundling the program as a standalone.

This library has no dependencies itself, nor does any other library of the project depend on it. What could cause this problem, and how to fix it? sbt version is 0.12.4.

Comment: and what `show library-dependencies` shows?

Comment: @AlexIv Ah, too late, I just fixed it. It does show up in `library-dependencies`, but I can't verify anymore if it was the case five minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [variant of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724751/sbt-silently-fails-to-import-a-dependency). Although other than in the linked question the `.jar` file *does* end up in `lib_managed`, it still isn't somehow "considered important" by sbt.

The solution is the same.

```
$ rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache/mygroup/myartifact
```